# Why is this ImplicitRegion empty?

Tags: regions

I'm having trouble understanding why the following `RegionPlot` code produces results:

```
pred[x_, y_] := 
 0 < x <= 0.5 ∧ EvenQ@Floor[(y - 0.05)/0.1] ∨ 
  0.5 < x < 1 ∧ EvenQ@Floor[y/0.1]
RegionPlot[pred[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

while this code using `ImplicitRegion` produces an empty region:

```
Ω1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 < x <= 0.5 ∧ EvenQ@Floor[(y - 0.05)/0.1] ∨ 
   0.5 < x < 1 ∧ EvenQ@Floor[y/0.1], {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]
RegionPlot[
 RegionMember[Ω1, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears related to the use of `EvenQ`. So a possible workaround might be replacing with `Mod[#,2]==0&`.

Comment: Did you try it with `Mod[#,2]==0&`?  Wondering about the "might".  Also, region functionality should be getting a significant update in V10.0.2, which seems to be out (I don't have access yet).  I can confirm this problem exists in V10.0.1.

Comment: `ImplicitRegion` evaluates `EvenQ` on symbolic input, which returns `False`, since an expression with a symbol is not an even integral.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, I tried, and Mod is fine. About the "might": I'm not fluent in english and I accepted a suggested edit of my original post. If this behavior is by design I'll go for Mod, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - as seen in this [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/raw/2AN5Q9Bu), using `Mod` isn't a perfect solution.  It still produces an `ImplicitRegion` that isn't plottable directly.  Further, what attribute does `EvenQ` have that `Equal` does not, such that `Equal[x, 3]` remains unevaluated while `EvenQ[x]` gives `False`?

Comment: @JasonB Usually, and perhaps always, system functions that end in `Q` will always return `True` or `False`.  AFAIK, this is done programmatically (not through `Attributes` per se, if that's what you meant by attributes).  For example, if you wanted an `EqualQ`, you could use `TrueQ@ Equal[x, 3]`, which would return `False` if `Equal[x, 3]` does not evaluate to `True`. (This Q property means, for instance, that you can count `If` evaluating one of its next two arguments and so forth.)

Comment: @JasonB Regions are still not completely done, it seems (but I'm still on 10.3.0).  Adding `{x, y} \[Element] Reals` to your `pred` allows `DiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega]]` to work (but still not `RegionPlot`). One issue seems to be that `y == 1` contains a boundary of a segment that lies above `y == 1`.  If you change the `ImplicitRegion` to `{y, 0, 0.999}` and add the `{x, y} \[Element] Reals`, `RegionPlot` works.  --  You can also add the condition `0 <= y < 1` to `pred`.